# How do I compare two excels in VBA with firstName and lastName columns in one excel against full name in another excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA, I have a requirement which needs comparing to excels with one having FirstName and LastName against another excel having Full name.

We havebeen using VLookup, but since its we need to do this activity daily its getting difficult.

Need the result against all combinations? Like 
*if Firstname and Lastname excatly matches the FullName
* Only FirstName matches against first part of FullName or Middle part( if there is a middle name in Full name)
* Only SecondName Matches against Middle or Last part of FullName.

I am not sure how to do this in VBA, if its possible or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raaz

Comment: This is possible in VBA. It wouldn't be too difficult. I would approach this by splitting FullName into an array then do my comparison using the Instr Function or something similar or even a simple equals comparison. There is more to it, but that is the general idea.

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought so too, need to split the Full name. That's how we are currently doing using the V lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Like` operate with the `*` wildcard to represent multiple characters.

```
Sub Example()

    Const FirstName = "Elmer"
    Const LastName = "Fudd"
    Const FullName = "Elmer J. Fudd"

    Debug.Print FullName Like FirstName & "*" 'True
    Debug.Print FullName Like "*" & LastName ' True
    Debug.Print (FullName Like FirstName & "*") And (FullName Like "*" & LastName) 'True


End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a const if you are doing this check against a list of names.

Comment: I just used the const to shorten variable declaration and assignment.  The list variable needs to be on the right hand side.  For example if you are iterating over an array  `Cells(1,1) Like Arr(i) & "*"`